# Remove white spaces after paste with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried it ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfwzfamd/2/)), but it's not working.

How can you see the alert is empty. It's like .val() function starts before the string is copied.

```
$(document).on('paste', '#pasteIt', function(){
    alert($("#pasteIt").val());
    var withoutSpaces = $("#pasteIt").val();
    withoutSpaces = withoutSpaces.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    $("#pasteIt").text(withoutSpaces);
});
```

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get clipboard data

```js
$(document).on('paste', '#pasteIt', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // prevent copying action
  alert(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
  var withoutSpaces = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  withoutSpaces = withoutSpaces.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  $(this).val(withoutSpaces);
  // you need to use val() not text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pasteIt" placeholder="Paste something here">
```

Ref : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/paste-event-get-the-value-of-the-paste#14737000004101955

Comment: It works! Can you explain me what `e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text'));` do? Thank you!

Comment: `e.preventDefault(); `  is for avoiding the default action, that copying content to the input box. We don't need to perform, instead we need to paste the space removed value

Comment: `e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text')` is for getting clipboard content

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout`, this delays the check so the value is retrieved.
Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qfwzfamd/3/).

```
$(document).on('paste', '#pasteIt', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert($("#pasteIt").val());
        var withoutSpaces = $("#pasteIt").val();
        withoutSpaces = withoutSpaces.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        $("#pasteIt").val(withoutSpaces);
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: It does, but the solution of Pranav is a better one. Try that one out.

Comment: You must use `.val`, not `.text` to set the value

Comment: It doesn't work because 1 millisecond is far too short.  If you change the 1 to 250 (quarter of a second) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want this:

```js
$(document).on('paste', '#pasteIt', function(e) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var withoutSpaces = $("#pasteIt").val();
    withoutSpaces = withoutSpaces.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    $("#pasteIt").val(withoutSpaces);
  }, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<span>Enter: </span>
<input id="pasteIt">

</html>
```